# Why does my screen get random color lines and freeze with ANY operating system?

Tags: intel-graphics

I have an asus u52f with intel hd graphics, i5,6gb ram, it is not even a year old...but after a lil bit of having the computer on no matter what OS the graphics will glitch and the whole thing will freeze along with all these random color lines....ive tried win7 home, win7 ultimate, and now even ubuntu...please help me..this is my college computer and the semester will be starting back up very soon....oh and i forgot it works in safe mode...and had for a lil while worked after uninstalling drivers and disabling updates, then it started back up with out an update.

Comment: What are you using now as the OS?

Comment: Sounds like bad hardware, it should be covered under warranty if less than a year old, please have it repaired as soon as possible.

Comment: @izx You may want to make an answer out of that comment.

Comment: Anwar Shar- i am using Ubuntu 12.04 and also Windows 7 ultimate

Comment: IZX it is no longer under warranty...it is a refurb...wouldnt it be some sort of driver issue since when im in safe mode it has no problems at all

Answer (score 2):

Is is typical graphics chip overheating sympthom. It is hardware-related. You should check cooling system, clean it and apply new thermal grease. Take it to the service professional if you do not know how to disassemble your laptop.